# Does exponential distribution affect my solution?

Tags: statistics

I was struck at the beginning that it was dealing with the exponential distribution, but as I got the answers, it was nothing to do with the exponential distribution. so I can just ignore the "exponential" right?

[image: **My problem**]

Comment: I think the point is that the mean is an unbiased estimator of the parameter of an exponential distribution, given by its distributive mean. The mean of the geometric distribution is the reciprocal of the usual parameter used to define it so that would be a biased estimator (when not equal to $1$). I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Multipart comment** (may help you make sense of the problem).

(1) As @stiartstevemson says, $\bar X$ is an unbiased estimator for exponential mean $\beta$ because $$(\hat \beta) = E(\bar X) = \beta.$ The bias is 0 as you have seem.

(2) MSE = $E[(\hat \beta - \beta)^2] = Var(\hat \beta) + [b(\hat\beta)]^2.$
But have shown that the bias $b(\hat \theta) = 0,$ so the MSE is just the variance.

(I don't know why you conclude that you can/should ignore that you are dealing
with an exponential distribution. Your computations may seem familiar and
trivial, but for some other distributions such derivations get messy. So the assumption that the data are exponential is important.)